# xcode - autolayout - prevent overlap of logo + input with footer button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am having trouble preventing the text inputs from overlapping the footer button.

The footer has been anchored to the bottom of the screen.  All the elements up top (logo, title label, and 2 input boxes) all have relative constraints.  I try to add a constraint between that last input and the footer button but it pushes the footer off the screen on the smaller iphone.

What do I do??

https://github.com/civilordergone/taskfort_ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be in landscape only (I ran your code), where you have, for example, 320 points of vertical space, and an image (128pt), a text label (120pt), two text fields (30 each, for 60pt in total) and a 30pt button at the bottom. Already that's 338pt used, and we haven't accounted for the vertical spacing between your objects.

There simply isn't enough vertical space for all of these items to be vertically positioned while retaining their heights, so something has to be flexible: something has to be able to be vertically shrunk/compressed.  Your logo and app name (Taskfort) are two candidates.

Here are some of the changes and/or points of consideration:

1. An ImageView with a height and a width equality constraint will always be that size, but for your layout, it has to be able to be compressed. I removed the height & width constraints and added an Aspect Ratio constraint, so the logo keeps its aspect ratio, but can now scale. I added a relationship constraint between the logo's left side and the left side of the Taskfort label.
2. The image has a relationship to the top of the screen, saying it must be equal or greater (not less than) to 0.  This just means "the image can't be pushed off the top", which "less than" would allow it to be. (For example, if the image is pushed off the top by -40 points, that's still "less than 20").
3. The image has to be allowed to be vertically compressed. There is a property for "Vertical Compression Resistance" that was 250, and is now 249.  By setting it to 249, we're saying "If something has to give way, vertically, this object can be compressed."  Since we defined an aspect ratio constraint, if it does get compressed vertically, it'll be reduced horizontally by a proportionate amount so as to maintain the proportions of the logo.
4. To prevent the text fields from overlapping, their relationships are set to "equal or greater than".  Same for the Username text field to the label.
5. The challenge was in defining the relationship between Password and the Create Password button at the bottom.  I added a constraint that says their vertical distance must be greater than or equal to 20. This has a priority of 1000 (by default), so at all times, you get 20pt or greater between those two. **Without this, your password field and your button overlap**.
6. While step 5's constraint solves the overlap problem, it creates a new one in portrait orientation, where the password is now 20pt from the button, instead of being lovely white space.  To fix that, we add a second constraint between the password field and the button, and specify that the vertical distance is to be 228pt between them both.  Now that creates a constraint conflict because you now have two constraints that are both trying to define the vertical relationship between the button and the text field. The 20-pt one is required, it has to be there. But the other one is just a "nice to have, if we can fit it".

So you set the priority of the new one (the 228pt) to be low, such as a Priority of 250. Then the layout engine will use the required one (must be 20 pt or greater) and then it sees the other one ("make them 228") and it tries to do that. If it can't, such as in landscape, then it doesn't do it and doesn't complain, because you have the other constraint already that provides positioning information. If you're in portrait and you have enough space such that it can also apply the low priority constraint, then it'll do that too, and your portrait layout now gets a bigger gap between top and bottom.

When testing these layouts, use the Assist Editor in Preview split-screen mode so you can see the affects of your changes without needing to run the simulator. Here's a [guide on that.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/chapters/PreviewingLayouts.html)

[image: The UI in landscape and portrait, using Auto Layout]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this detailed report up and test it out.  This is my first dive into auto-layouts and I can already see it's going to pay-off HUGE dividends with the ever-growing # of iOS screen sizes.  I will try to implement your suggestions!

Comment: Hmm.. Now the top + bottom of the text are getting cut off.  Everything respects their positions though.  I don't know what I did differently than you, but the footer in the storyboard view is getting pushed off the screen but it displays properly in the simulator (it's displaying it off the screen too in the preview mode)

Comment: Ah I see why, I bumped down the constraints though I wonder why the preview doesn't update

Comment: Got it working!!  Though I wonder why the preview thing isn't showing the latest. Though id be interested in your tweaks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using an equality constraint, such as "the distance between lastInput.bottom and footer.top equals 20".  Instead, try an inequality operator, such as "the distance between lastInput.bottom and footer.top is equal or less than 20".

The attributes inspector for a constraint can let you change an equality to an inequality. Alternatively, you can double-click the constraint line (the UI in the storyboard editor) to get a quick pop-up for that.

Comment: I have tried adding the inequality operator but it doesn't seem to work.  Maybe I'm not anchoring the footer properly?  I have removed the inequality w/ this:  [https://github.com/civilordergone/taskfort_ios](https://github.com/civilordergone/taskfort_ios)